# Error with nicescroll scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I have a html document in which my chat is running. After receiving a new message i add it with .append. After that i want to scroll down to the bottom of the chat window. but due to some reason nicescroll wont scroll down completly.

my html element:

```
<div class="chat"> // class chat is unique
     <div id="chat_body">
         <span id="new_messages">
              //messages
         </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

the jquery script:

```
  $('#new_messages').append(messagehtml);
  $('.chat').getNiceScroll(1).resize();
  $('.chat').getNiceScroll(1).doScrollTop($('#chat_body').height() - 1, 1);
```

nice scroll(1) because there is another nicescroll element on the site.

Using `$('.chat').getNiceScroll(1).doScrollTop($('#chat_body').height() - 1, 1);` in the chrome developer console works perfectly fine.

I'm wondering why. Maybe `.append` is to slow?

Comment: try to use .append(messagehtml).promise().done(function(){ // refresh nicescroll here });

Comment: your code works fine .. but id must be unique .. http://jsfiddle.net/JPA4R/190/  and this with promise.done http://jsfiddle.net/JPA4R/191/

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. The only way I overcome it, is by adding one `<br/>` at the last of the content.

Answer (score 0):

make a change in the plugins, 
replace the following

```
(q=!1,e.stopImmediatePropagation(),e.preventDefault())
```

with

```
(q=!1,e.stopImmediatePropagation())
```